# Taco's Charleston Lyrics?

Tags: lyrics, synthpop

I have found [this relatively obscure song by Taco,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDSX4cqeAWc) called *Taco's Charleston*, and noticed that the lyrics for much of the song are "unknown" (represented by the question marks).

Can someone identify these unknown lyrics?

> Charleston, Charleston
>
> ???....
>
> Yes sir, that's my baby No sir, I don't mean maybe Yes sir, that's my
>   baby now
>
> Yes now, we've decided No no, we won't hide it Yes now, you're invited
>   now
>
> Hey by the way, by the way When we reach the preacher, I'll say
>
> Yes sir, that's my baby No sir, I don't mean maybe Yes sir, that's my
>   baby now

Comment: The original Charleston was composed by James P. Johnson. Check it out on Youtube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mashup of several different popular songs from the 1920's and 30's.  You can find most of the original songs listed independently.  For instance, the part at the beginning is:

> Charleston! Charleston! Made in Carolina!
>   Some dance, some prance
>   I'll say there's nothing finer than the
>
> Charleston, Charleston, gee how you can shuffle;
>   Every step you do, leads to something new.
>   Man I'm telling you, it's a lapazoo!
>
> Buck dance, wing dance will be a back number;
>   But the Charleston, the new Charleston,
>   That dance is surely a comer.
>
> Sometime, you'll dance it one time,
>   That dance called Charleston,
>   Made in South Caroline!

http://lyricsplayground.com/alpha/songs/c/charleston.shtml